# Accessing array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am Iterating through an array of locations that have longitude and latitude values. I am using these values to call the Open Weather API asynchronously. I am then looping through the returned JSON array to grab each location's forecast date and time, forecast description, and the forecast icon. Then I want to store them in an array.

My issue is when I try to push the data back to the 'forecastArray' (so I can place the data into my HTML dynamically with jQuery) I can't access the data, when I console.log it the browser it returns as 'undefined'. the actual array will log to the browser but I can't assign the data to variables.

I am fairly new to web development so I would appreciate any advice given. I must not be understanding the scope limitations.

Here is my code:

```html
let ForcastArray = []
                        
                        for (let i = 0; i < cities1Array.length; i++) {


                            // console.log(citiesArray1[i])

                            let lat = citiesArray1[i][0]

                            let lng = citiesArray1[i][1]

                            openWeatherForcast(lat, lng).then(forcast => {
                                    
                                // console.log(forcast)
                                
                                for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

                                    // console.log(forcast['list'][j]['dt_txt'])
                                    let dateTime = forcast['list'][j]['dt_txt']
                                 
                                    // console.log(forcast['list'][j]['weather'][0]['description'])
                                    let description = forcast['list'][j]['weather'][0]['description']
                                    // console.log(forcast['list'][j]['weather'][0]['icon'])
                                   
                                    let iconcode = forcast['list'][j]['weather'][0]['icon'];
                                    let iconurl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + iconcode + "@2x.png";
                                    ForcastArray.push(dateTime, description, iconurl)
                                    
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        
                        console.log(ForcastArray)

                        // Returns:

                        // []
                        //     0: "2020-09-27 12:00:00"
                        //     1: "few clouds"
                        //     2: "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/02d@2x.png"
                        //     3: "2020-09-27 15:00:00"
                        //     4: "clear sky"
                        //     5: "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01d@2x.png"
                        //     6: "2020-09-27 18:00:00"
                        //     7: "clear sky"
                        //     8: "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01n@2x.png"
                        //     9: "2020-09-27 21:00:00"
                        //     10: "few clouds"
                        //     11: "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/02n@2x.png"
                        //     12: "2020-09-28 00:00:00"
                        //     13: "scattered clouds"
                        //     14: "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03n@2x.png"
                        //     15: "2020-09-28 03:00:00"
                        //     16: "light rain"
                        //     17: "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10n@2x.png"
                        //     18: "2020-09-28 06:00:00"
                        //     19: "light rain"
                        //     20: "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png"
                        //     21: "2020-09-28 09:00:00"
                        //     22: "moderate rain"
                        //     23: "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png"
                        //     24: "2020-09-28 12:00:00"
                        //     25: "light rain"
                        //     26: "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png"
                        //     27: "2020-09-28 15:00:00"
                        //     28: "overcast clouds"
                        //     29: "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/04d@2x.png"
                        //     length: 30
                        //     __proto__: Array(0)
                        
                        console.log(ForcastArray[0])
                        
                        // Returns:

                        // undefined
```

Comment: can u shoe more code pls? the api fetching stuff is important. maybe u have some timing issues with a async call to the api

Answer (score 0):

If the array is populated you should be able to access it with the array access operator (the square brackets) `[0]` like you wrote (`console.log(ForcastArray[0]`).

As Deniz pointed out this is probably a timing issue. You should put the console.logs inside your `.then()` block, the array will be accessible when this block is executed.

```
openWeatherForcast(lat, lng).then(forcast => {
    
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

        // console.log(forcast['list'][j]['dt_txt'])
        let dateTime = forcast['list'][j]['dt_txt']
    
        // console.log(forcast['list'][j]['weather'][0]['description'])
        let description = forcast['list'][j]['weather'][0]['description']
        // console.log(forcast['list'][j]['weather'][0]['icon'])
    
        let iconcode = forcast['list'][j]['weather'][0]['icon'];
        let iconurl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + iconcode + "@2x.png";
        ForcastArray.push(dateTime, description, iconurl)
        
    }

    console.log(ForcastArray[0])
})
```

You can count the returned promises and see if they match the number of cities (length of cities1Array or citiesArray1). When returned promises == citiesArray1.length you can execute another function to start the DOM manipulation (insert the data in your HTML via jQuery).